# StackBot - Making it easy to post StackExchange questions to Twitter

Tags: app, questions, c#, twitter

[image: Logo]

## About

StackBot is a small C# application that is designed to post interesting questions to a Twitter account at specified intervals.

### License

StackBot is released under the [Ms-PL license](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/ms-pl.html).

### Download

You can find instructions on using the application, project files (for Mono and Visual C# 2010), and the source code at:
          **[stackbot.quickmediasolutions.com/](http://stackbot.quickmediasolutions.com/)**

### Platform

StackBot will run on any supported .Net platform. This includes Mono, so you can run it in Linux and on your Mac.

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I like the logo