# How is the Hot Apps and Libraries list determined?

Tags: support, meta, stackapps, libraries, apps

I was wondering how the [Top Apps / Hot Apps and Libraries](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps) list is determined. It currently looks like this (click to enlarge):

[image]

I've tried to compare it with the list of questions tagged [app](/questions/tagged/app), both the ['newest'](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app?sort=newest) and the ['active'](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app?sort=active) tab, and while there are similarities, there are also differences, even when filtering out only those with a couple of upvotes.

- [Pyle: A Stack Exchange client for UWP (Placeholder)](https://stackapps.com/q/7575/34061)

  - +2, asked Aug 31st, edited Sep 26nd
- [StackInTheFlow - An IntelliJ plugin to query Stack Overflow](https://stackapps.com/q/7542/34061)

  - +7, asked Aug 14th, edited Aug 15th
- [Stack 10 - UWP App for Windows 10 & Windows 10 Phone](https://stackapps.com/q/7116/34061)

  - +5, asked Nov '16, edited Aug 31st
- [StackBot - Making it easy to post StackExchange questions to Twitter](https://stackapps.com/q/1907/34061)

  - +7, asked Jan '11, edited Aug 6th
- [Not a real question – A Stack Exchange game](https://stackapps.com/q/1369/34061)

  - +61, asked Aug '10, edited Mar 17th

Yes, they all have been recently active (except maybe for the last one), but that's not the only criteria. Maybe there is some kind of formula like the one for [hot network questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756/295232)?

Comment: This is a cross-site duplicate of: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-questions-in-the-hot-tab-selected

Comment: Somehow I never noticed other sites have 'hot' tabs as well (StackApps has one of those, too). You're saying that it's basically that + a filter on [app], [library] (and [script] for the other tab)?

Comment: Also, [this question](https://stackapps.com/questions/7626/stackview-ios-application-placeholder) appears on StackApps' hot tab, but not on the Apps tab. So additional filtering (score?) is somehow active as well.

Comment: Yes, that recipe + the tag filter is probably how it's done.